# my plugin not working for different callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-plugins

I'm developing a plugin for context menu of different divs

```
<div>
  <div class='first'>some data</div>
  <div class='second'>some data</div>
  <div class='third'>some data</div>
  <div class='fourth'>some data</div>
</div>
```

This is the menu to display as context menu:

```
<ul id='cmenu'>
 <li id='menuItem1'>Item1</li>
 <li id='menuItem2'>Item1</li>
 <li id='menuItem3'>Item1</li>
 <li id='menuItem4'>Item1</li>
 <li id='menuItem5'>Item1</li>
 <li id='menuItem6'>Item1</li>
</ul>
```

How this plugin works: it changes the list of menu items for every division and the callbacks for menu items are also changed.

```
(function($) {
     $.fn.cnxtmenu = function(options) {
          var defaults = {
              'menuid' : '',
               item1 : function() {},
               item2 : function() {},
               item3 : function() {},
               item4 : function() {},
               item5 : function() {},
               item6 : function() {},
          },
          opt = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

          var mid = '#'+opt.menuid, seldiv;
          this.live({
               "contextmenu" : function(e) {
                     seldiv = $(this);
                     if ($(this).hasClass('first')) {
                         //change the menu list         
                     }
                     else if($(this).hasClass('second')){
                         // change the menu list to display different items 
                     } 
                     else if($(this).hasClass('file-list')){
                         //differ list  
                     }
                     else if($(this).hasClass('dstore_file-list')){
                         //differ menu list
                     }
                     $(mid).css({
                          top : e.pageY + 'px',
                          left : e.pageX + 'px'
                     }).show();
                     return false;
                 }
            });

            $(mid).children('li').unbind('click').click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault(); 
                switch(this.id) {
                    case 'menuItem1':
                        opt.item1(this, seldiv);
                        break;
                    case 'menuItem2':
                        opt.item2(this, seldiv);
                        break;
                    case 'menuItem3':
                        opt.item3(this, seldiv);
                        break;
                    case 'menuItem4':
                        opt.item4(this, seldiv);
                        break;
                    case 'menuItem5':
                        opt.item5(this, seldiv);
                        break;
                    case 'menuItem6':
                        opt.item6(this, seldiv);
                        break;
            }
            $(mid).hide();
            return false;
        });

        $(mid).click(function() {
            $(mid).hide();
        });
        $(document).click(function() {
            $(mid).hide();
            });
       }
})(jQuery);
```

and I am using this plugin like this.

```
$('.first').cnxtmenu({menuid:'cmenu',
    item1:some callbacks
});

//...

$('.fourth').cnxtmenu({menuid:'cmenu',
     // soem differt callbacks.
});
```

For all the four div are assigned different callbacks.

My problem is that callbacks are not differing for the selectors, the only last i.e. fourth selector's callbacks are executing. And callbacks are triggering many times.

Help me what's wrong in my code please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Describe how it supposed to work, please

Comment: it should display the menu for different divisions and trigger the callbacks assigned for that divisions

Comment: Menu is same for all divisions and the only items are change that means hide some items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your problem you are assigning callbacks in wrong way. and the callbacks are assigning as you specified for last division. So **you need to assign the callbacks inside the contextmenu  function**.

second as many times you call the plugin, the plugin code will also execute and as your code the callbacks are also assign at the onload. no need to worry after the code change.

Answer (score 1):

In the example given you are passing the list `cmenu` as the same object to each call to `cnxtmenu()`.  Since `cmenu` is persistent, when you `unbind` click listeners, you are removing the previously attached listeners and replacing them with a new one.

You either need to pass a different context menu to each call to `cnxtmenu()` or you could try rearchitecting the thing have multiple callbacks, but filter them out based on which element triggered the context menu.

Also, unless you are constrained to some version below jQuery 1.7, you should be using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/), instead of `live()` and `unbind()`.

Comment: thanks for help!!. Can you tell me whats wrong with displaying different items for different divs. and callbacks changing.

Comment: @kirankumar when you write a comment for certain person use `@` so that person will be notified. Edit your question and describe how it must work in details (for example: user clicks on `li#menuItem5`, `ul` must disappear, text in `div` must change) ... For now I understood nothing from your description

Comment: @caligula could u please tell me first y my code executing many times

Comment: @kirankumar when it is executing many times? After what action?

Comment: @kirankumar use `@` and it is executing two times cause you call your method two times e.g. `$('.first').cnxtmenu(` . As many times you created your menu that way, the code is running.

Comment: @caligula where was i am calling two times

Comment: @kirankumar In your second code example. `$('.first').cnxtmenu(...` is actually a call of the `.cnxtmenu` method of the jQuery object.